# PkRevealController and canEditRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I´m using `PKRevealController` for a slide bar menu, in my front controller I have a table view with `canEditRowAtIndexPath`, since I implement `PKRevealController` the Delete button that appears when swipe each cell stops showing, how can I get this working again?

Answer (score 3):

As of the time of this writing there is no known way (to me at least) to fix this on my end of the controller to properly work under all conditions imaginable. I.e. you need to handle said case yourself. Therefore, the controller exposes the `revealPanGestureRecognizer` property to you.

Simply, when instantiating the controller pass this option in your options dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
    PKRevealControllerRecognizesPanningOnFrontViewKey : @NO
};
```

This will disable pan-based reveal for the entire front view. Now, you can use the revealPanGestureRecognizer and add it to any view you desire to be panned on, to enable gesture based reveal.

I'd advise (if working with a table based environment with editable cells) you to add the `revealPanGestureRecognizer` to your front view controller's navigation bar (which it most likely has):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:self.revealController.revealPanGestureRecognizer];
```

And voila, panning doesn't interfere with your table view anymore.

(For more information on this, as well as some rationale see https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/pull/76 )

--

*Note:* There's another way to handle this using the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

though it can get kind of messy seeing how the UITableView has about five gesture recognizers and it handles the cell's edit modes globally...

Comment: Thanks for replying so soon, I´ll try this out!

Answer (score 1):

This works for who used `PkRevealController`:

```
self.revealController.frontViewController.revealController.recognizesPanningOnFrontView = NO;
```

This worked for me.

Updated: I have added the code from where I am push reveal View controller. Now on view controller only sliding will be enable and in other class won't.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([viewController isMemberOfClass:[ViewController class]])
        self.revealController.frontViewController.revealController.recognizesPanningOnFrontView = YES;
    else
        self.revealController.frontViewController.revealController.recognizesPanningOnFrontView = NO;
}
```

you must be push PKRevealcontroller. So from that class use `UINavigationController` delegate method and put the check and add these lines.

We can use Option parameter while initializing the reveal controller but that did not solve my purpose as whole.

Comment: where in the code would that line go? I can't seem to get it to take effect. thanks :) I'm looking to disable the right swipe on a certain view - a detail view after a table row item has been selected from the frontVC.